Delete keys in nested json file on windows shell script
I want to delete some keys and its values in a nested json file on windows in a shell .cmd script, but get errors.
Looks like a quoting issue and more.
Input file:
{
  "account_tracker_service_last_update": "13351819478658924",
  "alternate_error_pages": {
    "backup": true,
    "enabled": false
  },
  "announcement_notification_service_first_run_time": "13272713839385778",
  "autocomplete": {
    "retention_policy_last_version": 120
  },
  "browser": {
    "app_window_placement": {
      "DevToolsApp": {
        "always_on_top": false,
        "work_area_top": 0
      }
    },
    "clear_data": {
      "time_period": 4
    },
    "last_clear_browsing_data_tab": 1
  }
}

I want to remove some more keys but started with just one: alternate_error_pages
Tried jq-win64.exe "del[\".alternate_error_pages\"]" example.json and got:
jq: error: del/0 is not defined at , line 1:
del[".alternate_error_pages"]
jq: 1 compile error
Next: jq-win64.exe "del(.name=\"alternate_error_pages\")" example.json but get:
jq: error (at example.json:23): Invalid path expression with result {"account_tracker_service_...
I tried a few more things but these are gone from my script already.
What I really want to achieve is to remove these keys:
.alternate_error_pages
.autocomplete
.browser.app_window_placement.DevToolsApp

But I did not manage to remove one single top level key.

del is a function and needs (). There is also no need to quote (or escape) the keys.
Use del(.key1, .key2, .key3) as the filter

> jq-windows-amd64.exe "del(.alternate_error_pages, .autocomplete, .browser.app_window_placement.DevToolsApp)" json
{
  "account_tracker_service_last_update": "13351819478658924",
  "announcement_notification_service_first_run_time": "13272713839385778",
  "browser": {
    "app_window_placement": {},
    "clear_data": {
      "time_period": 4
    },
    "last_clear_browsing_data_tab": 1
  }
}


Wow just works simple and clean, thanks a lot!
